# After installing basemap in linux environment my pyart and netCDF4 module are not working. I am using python 3.6.8

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap

After installing **basemap** by

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap-data-hires
```

pyart, are not working in python version 3.6.8 which was working good before basemap(1.2.0) in windows10

> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/share/proj/epsg'
>   (for pyart and from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap)

Comment: I am confused. You write in your title that you installed under linux and then say in your text that something was working before on your windows. So you are comparing different operating systems?

Comment: It was by mistake...operating system is linux onlu and not windows 10..pardon me

Comment: Make sure you do not install basemap to the base conda environment.

This user was able to find a workaround by [setting the environmental variable in the Python script](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/issues/420#issuecomment-479725764).

I experienced a similar issue on MacOS.  Unfortunately, the `epsg` folder was not in proj4.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58684131/6832816) you need the `epsg` file located [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/epsg).

One solution is to find the `epsg` file on your machine and redirect the environmental variable `$PROJ_LIB` to the appropriate folder.

In my case, I was unable to find the `epsg` file on my machine so I downloaded the epsg file to the `$PROJ_LIB` folder.  In your case, it seems that this is in `/share/proj/`.