# Basemap won't import because 'epsg' file or directory can't be found (MacOS, Anaconda, Jupyter Notebook)

Tags: python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, matplotlib-basemap

I am trying to use the Matplotlib Basemap toolkit but am running into a `FileNotFoundError` related to `epsg` when I try importing it.

I installed it using the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge basemap
```

Here's my import command:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
```

Here's the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d9467465a3b6> in <module>
----> 1 from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap

/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py in <module>
    154 # create dictionary that maps epsg codes to Basemap kwargs.
    155 pyproj_datadir = os.environ['PROJ_LIB']
--> 156 epsgf = open(os.path.join(pyproj_datadir,'epsg'))
    157 epsg_dict={}
    158 for line in epsgf:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/anaconda3/share/proj/epsg'
```

I'm completely new to Basemap, so I'm not sure how to go about fixing this. I'm using Jupyter Notebook to run Python 3.7.3 on macOS Mojave 10.14.6.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for this file: https://github.com/matplotlib/basemap/blob/master/lib/mpl_toolkits/basemap/data/epsg

Your `PROJ_LIB` env var does not appear to end with `.../site-packages`.
Please refer to https://ctcoding.wordpress.com/2019/01/29/solved-proj_lib-error-when-installing-basemap-on-windows-using-anaconda/

Take a look at `$ conda info --base`, and then run

```
$ find `conda info --base` -name epsg
```

to verify the file was installed in the intended directory.
Adjust `PROJ_LIB` to point there.

Comment: Thanks @J_H. A few questions:

1) When I run $ find `conda info --base` -name epsg
I get `/anaconda3/pkgs/proj4-5.2.0-h0a44026_1/share/proj/epsg`
How exactly do I adjust PROJ_LIB to point to the epsg file?

2) I don't  need to replace my current epsg file with the file you linked, right?

3) The Wordpress article you linked is for Windows. How would I modify what it suggests for Mac? Is it necessary?

Thanks again

Comment: I tried this from Jupyter Notebook:
`import os 
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '/anaconda3/pkgs/proj4-5.2.0-h0a44026_1/share/proj/'`

`from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap`

and it seemed to work...at least it didn't raise an error.

Should that solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, that is enough to let basemap know where it has been installed, so it can open a file that shipped as part of the package.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to be a fix that I have to implement each time I run a programming environment like if I open a new Jupyter Notebook or run Python from a command-line-based environment. Is there a way to get the environment variable set up more permanently so I don't have to run the command for each new programming session?

Comment: Thanks. I'm not too familiar with bash scripting, so what would be the syntax on that?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear your google isn't working. Here's what mine said: https://www.tecmint.com/set-unset-environment-variables-in-linux/

Comment: Figured it out. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As said in another comment run this command in terminal or in the Anaconda executor thing (if you run it in Anaconda make sure you redo the single quotes part if you copy and paste the below):

```
$ find `conda info --base` -name epsg
```

When you run that command several file paths should come up. Before you import Basemap into your program put the following lines:

```
import os
os.environ['PROJ_LIB'] = '/Users/XXXXXXXX/opt/anaconda3/pkgs/proj4-5.2.0-h0a44026_1/share/proj/'
```

where the whole line in quotes is the filepath that appears from the first line of code (without the epsg/ at the end). The part in quotes above is what appeared for me. If no file paths come up or another issue arrises check out the github pages on this (just google the error) or try

```
conda install -c conda-forge proj4
```